# How to upload files to apache server root document directory by using filezilla ftp?

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, ftp

I'm trying to upload files to apache root document directory on windows 7 system (c:\apmsetup\htdocs).

so I do this, filezilla client shows access denied error message.

How to upload files to apache root doc directory?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do that! Apache is a webserver not a FTP server.
You should think of running a FTP Server and give that path of apache directory to it.

Download:
https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server
Also Check:
http://lifehacker.com/339887/build-a-home-ftp-server-with-filezilla